# Extracting Strings from a downloaded file

Tags: java

I need some help with editing a string and adding parts of that String to an `ArrayList` of strings:

```
public ArrayList<String> strings = new ArrayList<String>();
```

Basically my program reads a file from the internet and sets the contents of the read file as a String. I then want to read through the strings contents to find keywords like:

```
website=http://google.com
website=http://stackoverflow.com
```

I just want to add the parts after the `website=` to the array of strings, I also want to take into account that the `website` part is there because I will also have other things apart from `website=` such as `ping=`. I just don't know how I would do this.

If anybody could help me with this or explain a better way I could go about doing the hole method itself, that would help me out a lot.

Comment: how website= and ping= will be seprated?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So you have all that in one string? Then regular expressions might be a way to go, e.g. `Pattern` and `Matcher` along with the expression `website=(\S+)`.

Example:

```
String input = "website=http://google.com ping=http://pong.com website=http://stackoverflow.com";

Pattern p = Pattern.compile( "website=(\\S+)" );
Matcher m = p.matcher( input );

while( m.find() )
{
  System.out.println(m.group(1));
}
```

Output:

```
http://google.com
http://stackoverflow.com
```

Answer (score 0):

There is no single way but some things you can use are :
1. String.contains() Function : Use this to see if a string contains a substring. To account for case sensivity , you can use like :

```
str = "website="
yourString.toLowerCase().contains(str.toLowerCase())
```

You can combine with `if` logic like :

```
if(yourString.toLowerCase().contains(str.toLowerCase())
//do something
```

You can get index of the character following `website=` like :

```
str="website=";
int index = yourString.indexOf(str)+str.length();
```

Use all the above to write a logic for your needs.